# Error in Postman: Spec File with name - example_spec - could not be found

Tags: java, spring, http, postman

I am trying to hit endpoints from my controller. I want to parse a text file based upon a specification file.

Here is the controller:

```
package com.example.justin_revature_project.controllers;

import com.example.justin_revature_project.exceptions.InvalidInputException;
import com.example.justin_revature_project.exceptions.SpecFileNotFoundException;
import com.example.justin_revature_project.exceptions.UserNotFoundException;
import com.example.justin_revature_project.models.MetadataFile;
import com.example.justin_revature_project.models.ParsedFile;
import com.example.justin_revature_project.models.SpecFile;
import com.example.justin_revature_project.models.User;
import com.example.justin_revature_project.services.MetadataFileService;
import com.example.justin_revature_project.services.ParsedFileService;
import com.example.justin_revature_project.services.SpecFileService;
import com.example.justin_revature_project.services.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users/{username}/file")
public class ParsedFileController {
    private ParsedFileService parsedFileService;
    private SpecFileService specFileService;
    private UserService userService;
    private MetadataFileService metadataFileService;

    @Autowired
    public ParsedFileController(ParsedFileService parsedFileService, SpecFileService specFileService, UserService userService, MetadataFileService metadataFileService){
        this.parsedFileService = parsedFileService;
        this.specFileService = specFileService;
        this.userService = userService;
        this.metadataFileService = metadataFileService;
    }

    @GetMapping("")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public List<ParsedFile> getParsedFilesByUserId(@PathVariable String username) throws UserNotFoundException {
        return this.parsedFileService.findParsedFilesByUserId(this.userService.findByUsername(username).getId());
    }

    @PostMapping("specFile/{specFileName}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
    public ParsedFile postNewParsedFileWithSpecFileName(@RequestParam("flatFile") MultipartFile flatFile, @PathVariable String specFileName, @PathVariable String username)
            throws SpecFileNotFoundException, IOException, UserNotFoundException, InvalidInputException {
        User currUser = this.userService.findByUsername(username);
        SpecFile specFile = this.specFileService.findByName(specFileName);
        ParsedFile newParsedFile = this.parsedFileService.insertFile(flatFile, specFile, currUser);

        // Add Parsed FileID to User who uploaded the file.
        this.userService.addParsedFileId(newParsedFile.getId(), currUser);
        // TODO: Find a way to update MetadataID field in parsedFile
        this.metadataFileService.insertMetadataFileLocal(new MetadataFile(newParsedFile.getId(), LocalDate.now()),
                "src\\main\\java\\resources\\" + currUser.getUsername() + "\\" + newParsedFile.getId().toHexString());

        return newParsedFile;
    }
}
```

This is the HTTP URL that I am trying to hit:

http://localhost:8080/users/jf451/file/specFile/example_spec

Here is the postman output:

I am using form-data and uploading two files.

The key from the first file is: flatFile with a value of file.txt
The key for the first file is: specFile with a value of example_spec.json

I am holding these files in the resources folder of my spring boot project.
I am lost as to why the endpoint is not working.

Here is the service for the Spec:

```
package com.example.justin_revature_project.services;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.example.justin_revature_project.exceptions.InvalidSpecFileException;
import com.example.justin_revature_project.exceptions.SpecFileNotFoundException;
import com.example.justin_revature_project.models.SpecFile;
import com.example.justin_revature_project.models.User;
import com.example.justin_revature_project.repositores.SpecFileRepository;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class SpecFileService {
    private SpecFileRepository specFileRepository;

    @Autowired
    public SpecFileService(SpecFileRepository specFileRepository){
        this.specFileRepository = specFileRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Find a SpecFile by the name of the SpecFile
     * @param name the name of the SpecFile being searched for
     * @return The SpecFile of the given name
     * @throws SpecFileNotFoundException when a specfile of the given name is not found
     */
    public SpecFile findByName(String name) throws SpecFileNotFoundException {
        return specFileRepository.findByName(name).orElseThrow(() ->
                new SpecFileNotFoundException("Spec File with name - " + name + " - could not be found" ));
    }

    public List<SpecFile> findListOfSpecFile(User user) {
        return this.specFileRepository.findByCreatedUserId(user.getId());
    }

    /**
     * Insert a new specfile given a MultipartFile representation of a json file and a String represention of the
     * ObjectID of the user who uploaded the specFile.
     * @param specFileAsJson The MultipartFile representation of the specfile
     * @param userID the userID of who uploaded the specFile
     * @return The specFile with the objectID
     * @throws InvalidSpecFileException when specFile does not have a name or DocOfFields
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public SpecFile insertNewSpecFile(MultipartFile specFileAsJson, ObjectId userID) throws InvalidSpecFileException, IOException {
        //TODO: Implement MultiLine parsing
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String specFileContent = HelperForService.parseFileToString(specFileAsJson);

        SpecFile newSpecFile = objectMapper.readValue(specFileContent, SpecFile.class);
        newSpecFile.setCreatedUserId(userID);

        //TODO: Validate that the specFile was added by a valid User
        //TODO: Validate that the same file is not uploaded twice (Optional)
        if(newSpecFile.getName() == null) {
            throw new InvalidSpecFileException("The specFile must have a 'name' field that is not null");
        }
        if(newSpecFile.getDocOfFields() == null) {
            throw new InvalidSpecFileException("The specFile must have a 'listOfFields' field that is not null");
        }
        return specFileRepository.save(newSpecFile);
    }
}
```

Why is the SpecFileNotFound exception being thrown?